# What does launchctl unload actually do?

Tags: launchd

When running `launchctl unload some.plist`, what is this command translated to specifically, in terms of UNIX commands, etc.

There is nothing in `.plist` files that specifies any "command line to run when the user specifies unload", so does macOS simply send a `kill` signal to the process? Or what does it do?

Answer (score 9):

## SIGTERM

launchd's `unload` command sends a **SIGTERM** signal to the associated job's child processes.

### Detached Processes

If a process launched by a launchd job has detached from it's parent process, then `unload` will not affect that process. This is often the case for [daemonised processes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287793).

### Original Source Code

You can download and inspect the [original launchd source code](https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/launchd/). `launchd` has since been rewritten and is proprietary to Apple but the original documents the intended behaviour on `unload`.

Comment: Very good answer! So it's `SIGTERM`, then. My next question is whether there's a standard UNIX (or macOS) way to know when a stopping a daemon has been completely finalised, because the prompt doesn't wait for that, does it? I'll be happy to post a new question about that if it doesn't fit within the scope of this question.

Comment: A modern UNIX process can use `kqueue` to be notified when a process terminates, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22960188 and Chrome's [kill_mac.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/base/+/master/process/kill_mac.cc) source. For more detailed answers and to ask for shell specific answers, please [ask a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2):

To best answer this question we can look at two things: UNIX commands and what is in a .plist.

Starting out with a .plist, the following code is usually there

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
  <string>someApplication</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The **CFBundleExecutable** identifies the name of the bundle’s main executable file. For an app, this is the app executable. For a loadable bundle, it is the binary that will be loaded dynamically by the bundle.

So typing `launchctl unload some.plist` will tell MacOS the key to locate the bundle’s executable file and 'unload' it or essentially kill it from the system.
*This is telling it at an application level*.

When using a UNIX command such as `kill <PID>` it is in reference to a specific process.

Looking at what is a Process vs Application [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131112/what-is-the-difference-between-application-and-process-in-os-x) is good reading

You can read further into what is in .plists and how they work over at [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009247)